# Updating ESRI mxd definition query variable via python?

Tags: arcpy, definition-query

we use definition queries to filter data to field users. We have up to 40-50 MXDs that are identical except for 1 variable in the definition query that allows the data for that MXD to be unique.
Example -  "DeploymentNumber='AA'" where 'AA' is the variable.
So, when we update MXDs, we would like to be able to use a python script to be able to update the variable - 'AA' component of our definition query in each layer without having to open each MXD, click on each layer and manually update (which in some cases is a 5 minute operation per MXD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to change this for your specific data since there might be layers that you don't want to change / don't have def queries set:

```py
import os
import arcpy

# top level directory where all the map docs are
path = r"<path>" 

# recursively search the directory for .mxd files
def getMXD(path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            if f.endswith(".mxd"):
                yield os.path.join(dirpath, f)


for mapdoc in getMXD(path):
    # might need to change wildcarding here
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mapdoc) 
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):        
        if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
            lyr.definitionQuery = "DeploymentNumber = 'AA'"
            mxd.save() # or mxd.saveACopy(<newpath>)

    del mxd, df
```

Comment: Was on my way to paste almost identical code :) suggest using `mxd_files = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")` and then `mxd_file_path = os.path.join(mxd_files_folder,mxd_file)`, a bit less code?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, good point (and a lot simpler!) if all your map docs are in the same folder. You'll want `os.walk()` to recursively drill down into sub-folders as `arcpy.ListFiles()` only works on whatever is set to `env.workspace`.

Comment: ah you are right. You would need to change env.workspace every time you are in another directory.. was always wondering why a parameter `input_folder` was not implemented for the `List*` functions in arcpy, is there any specific reason for that? Would love to have `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(input_folder)` :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, likely because the various `List*` functions are essentially file `globbers` with special consideration for ArcGIS data types (e.g., a file geodatabase is a folder). See the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module for something similar.

Comment: I will get into that tomorrow when I get back into the office and let you know how I go. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi guys, I managed to get the sample working well with my data. I have 1 problem though that I cannot solve - it wont update each layer in the MXD without specifying each implicitly in the code. So, to update all of the required layers in my MXD, I need to do code like this

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't work out how to paste the code darn it. So what I am meaning is even though I use the wildcard to return all layers, only the first layer honours the lyr.definitionQuery = "DeploymentNumber = 'AA'" command.